# Zalgo is crashing Safari 6

Tags: bug, status-declined, safari

Zalgo-ized comments cause Safari to crash.

If I go to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), and the Zalgo-ized comment isn't visible, I can do command and F fine.

However, if I click on "show 46 more comments" underneath bobince's answer, and then do command and F, the browser crashes.

Likewise, if I go to [Is it true that if someone reaches 200k reputation he/she gets a painting with a unicorn on it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a/261776#261776), where a Zalgo-ized comment is already visible, and do command and F, the browser crashes.

I'm on Safari Version 6.1.5 (7537.77.4), on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63).

Comment: Um, wouldn't this just be a browser issue? Does it happen on other non-Stack Exchange sites that also have Zalgo text? Or are you suggesting that SE shouldn't display Zalgo text?

Comment: No repro in IE11...which might bring you to the conclusion that Internet Explorer is a better browser than Safari...

Comment: Working fine with Safari under iOS 7 so likely OS X issue.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding CMD+F. Yay - I fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug localized to Lion. I just tested on a Lion system running 6.1.4, a Mountain Lion system running Safari 6.1.5, and my Mavericks system running Safari 7.0.5, and Command-F only crashes the Lion system under those conditions. The others behave just fine.

I'd usually say file a bug report with Apple, but I bet that fixing minor bugs with a two-(soon three)-version-old OS is probably fairly low on their list of priorities, particularly with the new OS versions all being free.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be an OS issue! Thanks for this.

Comment: I'm on OS X Yosemite (10.10) and Safari 8.0, and it no longer crashes.

Answer (score 10):

We are not in a position to fix browser/OS bugs.

It not feasible for us to sniff a specific browser/OS combo and for those simply sanitize the output from zalgo.

Comment: Zalgo cannot be sanitized. Any attempt would drive a man mad. N̹͉o̻͍̥̘̳͜ ͠m͉̟a̸̘̬̯̮c̼̰͙̺̠͙h҉͔̝̦i̺͙̼͚̼̮ǹ͓e͍̰̣̥̕ ̝̦c͔̩a̫̬n̡̞͈͇ ̞͠p̵͇̜r̭̫̘͔̯o͉͕̩c͓̝ͅȩ̟͓s̯̲s̥͎̜̹͈̬̳̕ ̙̬̮̥̣z̝̥̲a̟l҉̺̖̪̥̜̳̙g͙̪͇̼̯̦͓͘o̥͕̪.̯̝̱ ͓͎͞Ḭ̡ͅt̤̱͙ ̪̝͍wͅi͔͖l͙͎̜̣̼͈͇l̞̝̬̣̟̰͟ ̪c̹̹ͅo̖r̴̹̲̳̹r̝̥͈͚͘u͠p̀t̹̹̩̟̝̠ a̪͎̫̤̲͙͈͟l̳͉̞̤͙l̢͚ ̪̰̫͕̟͢ͅt̶̗h̠̼͔̙͔͜i̘͉̦͇̠̳n̠̹g͜s̥̖̮̹.̦͖͈ ͙T̴̫̭̰̩̺̹͇h̲e̼̦̗͙̖͙͘r̵e̮̲̜͞ ̖i̶̫̮̬̞ͅͅs̮̬͝ ̞͝n͍͓̭̱̖̼ͅo̗̺ ͙͍̪͇̞ḛ͕s̤̫̝͠ca͖̗̪̫̬͇̼p̡̦̙͍̟̭e̱͇̲̺͉̝̝.̳̙̦̠̙ ̮̰̬̣HE͖͍ ̤C͏͙͉̖̭O̭̗͍͟M̮͈͍̰̣͕̘͠E̗̣͍̜͠S̖̬͢.̝͝.̳̱͙̟.̞̣̻͈̩ͅ

Comment: @Cupcake - consider that you just killed any chance of the OP to read this ;)

Comment: Only if he attempts to `CMD + F`, apparently.